# Displays an existing message in a separate window by gmail API?

Tags: javascript, email, gmail, gmail-api

I'm developing javascript add-on where part of functionality is reminder. User entered some data and set what this email will be sent for example tomorrow.
My idea/task is to make possible what on pressing for example btn in my add-in it will open in gmail the needed email.
What I have is id of the email that I need re-open in gmail.

[image: scheme of calls]

Is it possible, if you know needed email id, in the gmail to open it again by add-in in separate window? Assuming you clicked btn in your add-on?
[image: how should it looks like]

Any ideas?
**btw I am using gmail api for my rest calls to app**

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to accomplish, I'm thinking of two alternatives.

#### Open existing message in a new window:

Use [setOpenLink](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action#setopenlinkopenlink) or [setOnClickOpenLinkAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action#setonclickopenlinkactionaction) to open a URL in a new tab when a button is clicked.

This tab can be full size or as a popup (via [setOpenAs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/open-link#setopenasopenas)):

```
var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
var url = message.getThread().getPermalink();
var openLinkButton = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('Open link')
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
      .setUrl(url)
      .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY));
var buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet()
    .addButton(openLinkButton);
var section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(buttonSet);
var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .addSection(section);
return card.build();
```

#### Create and display a draft:

Use [setComposeAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-action#setComposeAction(Action,ComposedEmailType)) to create and display a draft as a popup when a button is clicked. This draft can be standalone or a response to whatever message id you provide.

For example, in the sample below, a draft is created and displayed when clicking the button `Compose Reply`:

```
function createCard(e) {
  var composeAction = CardService.newAction()
      .setFunctionName('createReplyDraft');
  var composeButton = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Compose Reply')
      .setComposeAction(
          composeAction,
          CardService.ComposedEmailType.REPLY_AS_DRAFT);
  var buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet()
      .addButton(composeButton);
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
      .addWidget(buttonSet);
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .addSection(section);
  return card.build();
}

function createReplyDraft(e) {
  // ...Get messageId ...
  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  var draft = message.createDraftReply("I'm a draft!");
  return CardService.newComposeActionResponseBuilder()
      .setGmailDraft(draft).build();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Gmail interactions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/gmail/gmail-actions#gmail_interactions)

Comment: @lamblinchus/ Well solution is not appropriate because in my app I am using GMAIL API for rest calls. Not Gmail Interactions in my add-on

Comment: @Nyuokimi You're using a Gmail add-on but you're not using its functionalities? I'm not sure I understand your situation, can you provide more information about this, including relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @lamblichus . I am developing add-on for gmail. What uses GMAIL API .  I want a btn(contains id of existing email). On pressing on it(the btn) will open needed email.

Comment: @Nyuokimi I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're saying. I don't understand why you don't want to use the Gmail add-on methods like the ones from my answer. What API methods are you using instead?

Comment: @lamblichus. Okey in different words. My add-on sends rest request to my server. In this server using GMAIL API I am filling data to email(compose).  Also server stores id's of emails what was sent. I want to open in separate window on btn press specific email.

Comment: I press btn(what holds id of email) and new window appear in gmail.

Comment: @Nyuokimi Consider providing the relevant parts of your code in your question, in order to fully understand your situation.

Comment: @lamblichus My question was if it possible if I know needed email's id to open it in new window using GMAIL API?

Comment: @Nyuokimi Using Gmail API, no. There's no API method to open URLs in browsers. You can of course (1) get the URL from the message ID, (2) open the URL in your browser, but that has nothing to do with Gmail API.